# ¿Inserción de datos muy lenta en base de datos con mecanismo InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, innodb

Primero estoy exportando a un script `sql` la estructura de una base de datos que esta creada con mecanismo `MyISAM`.

Luego ejecuto ese script para crear una base de datos vacía solo con la estructura de las tablas.

Después convierto las tablas de `MyISAM` a `InnoDB` sin problema.

Por ultimo estoy exportando a otro script sql los datos y lo ejecuto en la nueva base de datos ya con mecanismo `InnoDB`.

El problema esta en ejecutar el script que solo tiene datos demora **demasiado** insertando en una hora solo inserto datos en 10 tablas y la tabla con mas registros solo tiene 800000 no es para que demore tanto, convierto primero las tablas y después exporto los datos porque al convertir las tablas junto con los datos demora mucho más.

¿Por qué demora tanto en `InnoDB`?¿Es más lento para insertar los datos?
¿Cómo puedo insertar más rápido los datos?
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para agregar a la respuesta de @Rene; si se está utilizando un diseño de base de datos relacional, i.e., con llaves foráneas, no se puede utilizar *MyIsam*.

La diferencia más notable entre *MyIsam | InnoDB* es el tema relacional, y la única razón por la cual se debería elegir *MyIsam* es si se va a utilizar la tabla más para lecturas muy recuentes e inserciones mas bien bajas. Teniendo en cuenta el tema de [diseño de base de datos relacional](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_de_datos_relacional)

Para responder exactamente el por qué toma más tiempo, me gusta mucho [ésta respuesta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16429) de DBA Stackexchange:

> The reason is very simple. When you insert a row into MyISAM, it just
>   puts it into the server's memory and hopes that the server will flush
>   it to disk at some point in the future. Good luck if the server
>   crashes.
>
> When you insert a row into InnoDB it syncs the transaction durably to
>   disk, and that requires it to wait for the disk to spin. Do the math
>   on your system and see how long that takes.

En español:

> Cuando se inserta una fila en MyISAM, simplemente se pone en la
>   memoria del servidor y espera a que el servidor lo ponga en el disco
>   en algún momento en el futuro.Buena suerte si el servidor se cae.
>
> Cuando se inserta una fila en InnoDB, se sincroniza la transacción con
>   el disco, y requiere que se espere a que el disco gire. Por ésto es
>   que toma tanto tiempo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me aclaras algunas dudas

Answer (score 2):

Ambos motores de almacenamiento tienen formas muy diferentes de almacenar datos en disco, por lo que la conversión es tardada.

`MyISAM` es un formato que ocupa menos memoria para almacenar en comparación a `InnoDB. De acuerdo a la [documentación](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html)

> Las características adicionales de fiabilidad y escalabilidad de InnoDB requieren más almacenamiento en disco que las tablas MyISAM equivalentes. Puede cambiar ligeramente la columna y las definiciones de índice, para una mejor utilización del espacio, un menor consumo de E / S y memoria al procesar conjuntos de resultados y mejores planes de optimización de consultas, haciendo un uso eficiente de las búsquedas de índices.

Por lo tanto, es normal que la conversión sea tan tardada.